# How to correct OCR segmentation errors using bounding rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, ocr, tesseract, error-correction

I'm using tesseract for OCR and have noticed, that sometimes segmentation errors occur and characters, that "obviously" belong together are split into separted strings.

Based on a list of characters and their bounding boxes found in one text line and the prilimanary OCR result suggesting, which of these characters belong to one word, which algorithms can I apply to correct segmentation errors or verify the result?

So this this the data available:

```
List<Word> words;
for(Word word : words){
    for(Char c : word.getChars()){
        char ch = c.getValue();
        Rectangle rect = c.getRect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **OCR post-correction** that takes into account the characters and words, but admittedly **not the bounding boxes**, one common practice is

- to use a **dictionary of valid words**, as comprehensive as possible
- to check the words that results from the OCR algorithm against that dictionary
- if a word cannot be found as an exact match in the dictionary, to try and find a *similar* one

To make this possible, you need to prepare the dictionary implementation so it enables a search for similar strings, also known as ***approximate string matching*** or *fuzzy string matching*.

The two main approaches for this that I am aware of are

- **Levenshtein atomata**, as described by [Schulz et al](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9946036749686151606&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) (DOI: 10.1007/s10032-002-0082-8)
- **Metric trees**, such as the BK tree described by [Baeza-Yates and Navarro](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=18181033095376770885&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) (DOI: 10.1109/SPIRE.1998.712978)

These approaches, as well as general approximate string matching approaches (such as search tries, q-grams matching and n-gram matching) all inherently use some kind of edit distance measure, more or less similar to [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). After **analysing the specific OCR errors** you are dealing with, you might want to **adjust the edit distance algorithm** and the other resources you are using to your specific needs. This may involve things like:

- Assume a lower substitution distance between characters that your OCR program confuses frequently, or characters that look particularly similar when rendered with the font or style you are dealing with
- Take possible segmentation errors into account by putting frequently occurring pairs of words in the dictionary (in addition to single words)
- Ensure that your dictionary contains as many named entities and other domain specific (or corpus specific) elements

Further more, you can try to use a **grammar**, and/or a **statistical language model**, such as a Hidden Markov Model or Conditional Random Field model -- similar to the models used by POS taggers -- to make word corrections *in context*.